# Eigenvalue decomposition of a covariance matrix using a fast Cholesky decomposition

Tags: gaussian-process, eigenvalues, state-space-models, cholesky-decomposition

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a $n \times n$ covariance matrix and assume that
the LDL' Cholesky decomposition can be obtained efficiently.  Can we
take advantage of this to obtain a fast eigenvalue decomposition of
$\mathbf{C}$?

As an example, $\mathbf{C}$ is the covariance of a discrete-time
Gaussian Process (GP) having a state-space representation or that of a
partially observed continuous-time state-space GP.  Using Kalman
filtering, the Cholesky decomposition can then be obtained with $O(n)$
operations instead of $O(n^3)$ for the general case. The eigenvalue
decomposition is required to investigate the Karuhnen-Loève expansion
of the GP.

To be more formal, the decomposition is $\mathbf{C} =
\mathbf{L}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{L}^\top$ where $\mathbf{L}$ is lower
triangular with ones on its diagonal and $\mathbf{D}$ is diagonal
say $\text{diag}(\mathbf{d})$. We can assume that we have a function
or a routine which for a given vector $\mathbf{y}$ with length $n$
computes efficiently the "innovation" vector $\mathbf{e} := \mathbf{L}^{-1}\mathbf{y}$ along with its variance vector $\mathbf{d}$. These two elements allow
the evaluation of the likelihood for the GP example. Using this
function we want to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: Fwiw, [scholar.google Cholesky eigenvalue](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=allintitle:cholesky+eigenvalue) -> a paper "Mathias, Fast accurate eigenvalue computations using the Cholesky factorization, 1996"; I don't understand the conditions offhand.

Comment: Thanks @denis. This is a step forward and I should read this.