# Square root of an almost diagonal matrix

Tags: gaussian-process, matrix-decomposition, hessian

Is there an efficient way to compute square root of an almost diagonal symmetric Hessian matrix, which is diagonal with the exception of the last two columns and last two rows?

[image]

Could the efficient solution be somehow using the [matrix diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#By_diagonalization), that the diagonalization could be effective for this type of matrix?

---

PS: Very likely it's not important for the answer at all, but I will include the exact definition of the matrix. The matrix is a modification of an originally diagonal Hessian from [Rasmussen & Williams 2006 (Gaussian Processes in Machine Learning)](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf), defined as (orig. definition see pg. 42-43, formula 3.15):

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
W_{ii} &=& -{\partial^2 \over {\partial{f_i^2}}}\log p(\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{f},g,h) = \pi_i(1-\pi_i); \text{  for } _{i = 1 \dots n-2} \\
W_{i,n-1} &=& -{\partial^2 \over {\partial{f_i}\partial{g}}}\log p(\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{f},g,h) = x_{1,i}\pi_i(1-\pi_i); \text{  for } _{i = 1 \dots n-2} \\
W_{i,n} &=& -{\partial^2 \over {\partial{f_i}\partial{h}}}\log p(\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{f},g,h) = x_{2,i}\pi_i(1-\pi_i); \text{  for } _{i = 1 \dots n-2} \\
W_{n-1,n-2} &=& -{\partial^2 \over {\partial{g}\partial{h}}}\log p(\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{f},g,h) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} x_{1,i} x_{2,i}\pi_i(1-\pi_i) \\
W_{n-1,n-1} &=& -{\partial^2 \over {\partial{g^2}}}\log p(\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{f},g,h) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} x_{1,i}^2 \pi_i(1-\pi_i) \\
W_{n,n} &=& -{\partial^2 \over {\partial{h^2}}}\log p(\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{f},g,h) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} x_{2,i}^2 \pi_i(1-\pi_i) 
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where $\pi_i = \mbox{logit}^{-1}(f_i+g x_{1,i} + h x_{2,i})$, and it's symmetric, i.e. $W_{i,j} = W_{j,i}$. The original likelihood function is:

$$p(\boldsymbol{y}|\boldsymbol{f},g,h) = \prod_{i=1}^{n-2} \mbox{logit}^{-1}(y_i (f_i+g x_{1,i} + h x_{2,i}))$$

for $y_i \in \{-1,1\}$.

I need to compute $W^{1 \over 2}$ for the formula 3.26 (pg 45) in the original paper.

---

**EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED.** I found a great paper - [Eisenfeld 1976 - Block Diagonalization and Eigenvalues](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(76)90026-4).
The Corollary 3.1 is awesome, but it only works for upper triangular matrices. So I implemented the general iterative computation of root matrices in Theorem 4.1,
but even with very beautiful matrices with all eigenvalues positive and not small and full rank, the iterations strongly diverged, leading to exponentially higher and higher differences (see the code below).

So in the end, I was saved by great @Yves' comment "Can't you use a Cholesky square root rather than a symmetric one? I believe that the matrix inversion lemma would work as well in (3.27) if we write $W=LL^T$".

Excellent idea!!! I did exactly that! The Cholesky decomposition of my matrix can actually be done much simpler and very fast!! I used the [Block LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_LU_decomposition) and this completely solved my problem :)

I don't post this as an answer, since it did not answer the original question of the square root; but it solved my problem, Cholesky is perfect fit in this context as well.

Not sure why the Eisenfeld 1976 iterations didn't work - I post my code here:

```
# Implementation of Eisenfeld 1976 - Block Diagonalization and Eigenvalues
# Generate matrix

<- 8
q <- 3
n <- p+q

p <- 100
q <- 10
n <- p+q

p <- 2900
q <- 100
n <- p+q

# generate matrix
#pi <- runif(p, 0, 1)
fi <- rnorm(p)
gi <- rnorm(q)
z <- 2*q # pocet occassions
xcov <- matrix(rnorm(z*q), nrow = z, ncol = q)
pi <- inv.logit(matrix(fi, nrow = p, ncol = z) + matrix(xcov %*% gi, nrow = p, ncol = z, byrow = TRUE))
W <- diag(n)
diag(W)[1:p] <- apply(pi*(1-pi), 1, sum)
#W[1:p,(p+1):n] <- xcov * matrix(pi*(1-pi), nrow = p, ncol = q)
for (j in 1:q) {
    W[1:p,p+j] <- (pi*(1-pi)) %*% xcov[,j,drop = FALSE]
}
W[(p+1):n,1:p] <- t(W[1:p,(p+1):n])
for (i in 1:q) { # nevim jak toto vektorizovat... 3D matice :-D (nebo lze vice nasobenimi?)
    for (j in 1:q) {
        W[p+i,p+j] <- sum( (pi*(1-pi)) %*% (xcov[,i]*xcov[,j]) )
    }
}


# notation by Eisenfeld:

A <- W
stopifnot(all(dim(A) == p+q))

E <- A[1:p,1:p]
F <- A[1:p,(p+1):n]
G <- A[(p+1):n,1:p]
H <- A[(p+1):n,(p+1):n]

# computation by Eisenfeld

# E is diagonal
E.inv <- E
diag(E.inv) <- 1/diag(E.inv)

# in my case also t(F) == G, and H is symmetric

# Theorem 4.1 - iterative computation of the roots R1, R2

# test the conditions
#a =  E.inv %*% t(F) det(F)*det(E.inv)

it <- 0
itmax <- 10

tol <- 1e-6
Y1diff <- Y2diff <- 1
Y1.new <- matrix(0, nrow = q, ncol = p)
Y2.new <- matrix(0, nrow = p, ncol = q)

#Y1.new <- matrix(rnorm(p*q)/1000, nrow = q, ncol = p)
#Y2.new <- matrix(rnorm(p*q)/1000, nrow = p, ncol = q)
while ((Y1diff > tol || Y2diff > tol) && it < itmax) {
    it <- it + 1
    Y1 <- Y1.new
    Y2 <- Y2.new

    # f1(Y) = -YFYE-l + HYE-1 + GE-l
    Y1.new <- -Y1 %*% F %*% Y1 %*% E.inv + H %*% Y1 %*% E.inv + G %*% E.inv

    # f2(Y) = E-1YGY + E-1YH - E-1F
    Y2.new <- E.inv %*% Y2 %*% G %*% Y2 + E.inv %*% Y2 %*% H - E.inv %*% F

    Y1diff <- max(abs(Y1.new - Y1))
    Y2diff <- max(abs(Y2.new - Y2))
    cat("Y1diff = ", Y1diff, ", Y2diff = ", Y2diff, "\n")
}
# doesn't converge even for beautiful positive definite matrix
```

Comment: Search keywords "arrowhead" "Cholesky decomposition" may help.

Comment: @Yves thanks! Can you please explain how would Cholesky decomposition help to find a square root? Thanks! :-)

Comment: Well the Cholesky root is sometimes called a square root, but I now understand now that you want to solve $\mathbf{X} \mathbf{X} =\mathbf{W}$ with $\mathbf{X}$ being *symmetric*. So just retain "arrowhead"...  I suspect that finding the eigenvalue decompostion of a matrix with an easy-to-get Cholesky decomposition should be simpler, but did not find help with [my question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/408758/10479).

Comment: Maybe write it as a block matrix, with one big diagonal block, and look at the formula for the inverse of a block matrix, for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks, this is good! But how would getting an inverse help me to get square root? It is non-trivial for me to see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't you use a Cholesky square root rather than a symmetric one? I believe that the matrix inversion lemma would work as well in  (3.27) if we write $\mathbf{W} = \mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}^\top$.

Comment: @Yves that's an excellent idea!! I did exactly that! You saved me man!! :-) See the update in my question :-)

Comment: If you feel that you've answered the question, you can write it in the Answer box below.

Comment: @Sycorax no I don't, please see the question update for reasoning.